# Problem running rtabmap_ros against a bag file

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been playing with the most excellent rtabmap_ros package on my Kobuki (Turtlebot 2) under ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.  I recorded a bag file from my robot using the following command:

```
$ rosbag record -b 512 -o ~/tmp/rtabmap /data_throttled_image/compressed /data_throttled_image_depth/compressedDepth/data_throttled_camera_info /tf /tf_static /scan /odom /joint_states
```

where I have used the suggested data_throttle launch file listed at http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#rviz.

I then try to run the rtabmap_ros/demo_robot_mapping.launch file against this bag file after changing the odom and scan topics in the launch file to match my robot's topics.  The demo_robot_mapping.launch file runs fine and the last INFO message during startup is:

```
[ INFO] [1448512439.761234227]: rtabmap 0.10.10 started...
```

But when I the play my bag file using the command:

```
$ rosbag play --clock my_bag_file.bag
```

I immediately get the following error in the rtabmap terminal:

```
[FATAL] (2015-11-25 20:34:11.368) OdometryEvent.h:45::generateCovarianceMatrix() Condition (uIsFinite(transVariance) && transVariance>0) not met!

*******
FATAL message occurred! Application will now exit.

*******
[ WARN] (2015-11-25 20:34:11.369) MainWindow.cpp:797::processOdometry() Empty cloudOdom!
[ERROR] (2015-11-25 20:34:11.369) CloudViewer.cpp:1127::setCloudVisibility() Cannot find actor named "cloudOdom".
[ERROR] [1448512451.431228091, 1448512183.861893627]: Can't call "pause" service
[rtabmap/rtabmap-1] process has died [pid 6798, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rtabmap_ros/rtabmap --delete_db_on_start odom:=/odom scan:=/scan rgb/image:=/data_throttled_image depth/image:= /data_throttled_image_depth rgb/camera_info:=/data_throttled_camera_info __name:=rtabmap __log:=/home/patrick/.ros/log/899bd3f6-93f4-11e5-941d-64006a04e0e0/rtabmap-rtabmap-1.log].
log file: /home/patrick/.ros/log/899bd3f6-93f4-11e5-941d-64006a04e0e0/rtabmap-rtabmap-1*.log
```

I don't see a topic named cloudOdom in my list of topics, nor is it in the [demo_mapping.bag](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B46akLGdg-uadXhLeURiMTBQU28&export=download) file used in the rtabmap demos.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** After downloading and installing version 0.10.12, I still get the same error as above but with one more message as follows:

```
rtabmap: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:101: boost::recursive_mutex::~recursive_mutex(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)' failed.
```

**UPDATE 2:** Here is a link to [the bag file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk4pyzyehzzw81j/rtabmap_test.bag?dl=0) that is causing the trouble.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221550/problem-running-rtabmap_ros-against-a-bag-file/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2015-11-26**:
The cause of the error was a left over running grid assembler node from a previous session.  Restarting roscore and starting from scratch solved the problem.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2015-11-26**:
I still [updated](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/542437c135a79698f847f25e84a4c8b3d7aea2f0) the code for the variance error. I [updated](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/commit/ee81bfc1d71591dbe61aa270b096a609034217e6) also the library for the "cloudOdom" error.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2015-11-26**:
The variance error would have been caused by infinity values in the odometry message. For the "cloudOdom", it was just that the rendered cloud in rtabmapviz could not be created (cloud was empty).

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2015-11-27**:
Thanks Mathieu!  However, I downloaded and compiled version 0.10.12 and I still get the same error, even after removing the Debian rtabmap and rtabma_ros packages just to be sure.  I do get one more error line that might help--I've posted an updated to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The problem was caused by large covariance values (`1.7976931348623157e+308`) in the Odometry messages:

```
$rostopic echo /odom
...
header: 
  seq: 7062
  stamp: 
    secs: 1448550366
    nsecs: 530036677
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_footprint
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.118375024097
      y: -0.23544191425
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.305612214835
      w: 0.952156066065
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.00191986217719
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
...
```

and there was a bug of double/float conversion in rtabmap node. This is now fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/8eea06c32beeb254a540c0f4afc11b87291afe8b).

Your bag helped me to correct another [issue](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/commit/096684ed9416e7ff110c27b46bb402e0213b7691) about variance when the link is not refined because the robot is not moving (under `RGBD/LinearUpdate` and `RGBD/AngularUpdate`). Thx!

I've taken [demo_robot_mapping.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_robot_mapping.launch) to test your bag, I just did a little modification to increase the number of loop closures found by lowering the parameter `LccIcp2/CorrespondenceRatio` (default 0.3, which is used to accept an ICP transformation):

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
 [...]
 <param name="LccIcp2/CorrespondenceRatio" type="string" value="0.2"/>
</node>
```

Here is the result (I also [added](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/736a909725317b92a6bb44c3c4a6eab583d00843) `cloud_ceiling_culling_height` parameter to filter the ceiling for better view):
[image: image description]

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2015-11-27**:
That did it--thanks Mathieu!  It seems the large covariance values may be deliberately published by the kobuki_node and may be used as "I don't know" values.  I see the same values in [this other post](http://answers.ros.org/question/212533/tf_nan_input-errors-from-use-of-ekf_localization_node/).

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2015-11-27**:
Also, thanks for adding the cloud_ceiling_culling_height parameter--it's like you were reading my mind as I was just about to ask if that could be added so I could see the room layout better. :-)